# Positioning widgets on top of Network Image based on X and Y coordinates

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to position custom widgets on top of an image based on X and Y coordinates. Think of it as an overlay. Until now, I have tried a solution, where I used a Stack in a combination with Positioned, to position widgets above the image. The problem arises when I try this solution on different screen sizes. The overlaid widgets are off, depending on the screen size I'm testing on.

Here's my current implementation:

```
      Expanded(
        child: InteractiveViewer(
          constrained: false,
          minScale: 0.1,
          maxScale: 2.0,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Image.network(widget.plan.image),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 2927,
                left: 6700,
                child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/svg/pin.svg", height: 200)
              )
            ],
          )
        ),
      )
```

Note that I'm also wrapping everything in InteractiveViewer because the Image I'm getting from the backend is very large.

EDIT: I have noted that for some reason the image dimensions are different on different displays. For example, photo dimensions on iPhone X are 10224x6526, where on iPhone 13 Pro Max image dimensions are 8192x5228. I am now investigating further why this is happening as this is probably the reason why custom widgets drawn on top are shifted on different screens.

EDIT 2: After a long research I've finally came across something. I own two physical devices - iPhone 12 and iPhone X. I was testing on simulator and something really odd happened; simulator is logging different image dimension simulating the same physical device - let me explain:

Original Image dimension coming from backend:

10224 × 6526

iPhone 12 simulator image dimension log after network call:

8192x5228

iPhone 12 PHYSICAL device image dimension log after network call:

10224 × 6526

iPhone X PHYSICAL device image dimension log after network call:

10224 × 6526

Which effectively means that something is working differently regarding the image scaling when using iOS simulator and physical device.

Comment: I would prefer using percentage position or `Aling` while it is about dynamic size.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this will be to try to position your items relative to the screen's width and height in percentage.

```
bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5 // 50% of the screen's height
left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3 // 30% of the screen's width
```

You are free to change the percentiles to suit you.

EDIT 2

```
x = (6700/width-of-photo) * 100

y = (2927/height-of-photo) * 100
```

With the issue concerning the size of the image, you might want to consider placing it inside a widget and giving it a max-height and max-width values.

Comment: I understand that your code gives me the percentage, but I have to work with specific X and Y coordinates. How could one translate for example coordinate x=6700 into percentage? Coordinate or point x here means offset from the left.

Comment: Percentiles must be relative to a specific value. You want coordinate x of what total x value. If it is 6700 of the width of the photo then your math will be x = (6700/width-of-photo) * 100 and y = (2927/height-of-photo) * 100. This will still make your overlaid widgets hidden from the screen since the value of your x and y are relative to the photo instead of the screen.

Comment: Your overlaid widgets will still be hidden because the photo is larger than the screen therefore an offset could be at a point not visible within the viewport of the phone's screen unless scrolled to.

Comment: thank you for the math. Widgets will not be hidden from the screen because I am wrapping everything in an InteractiveViewer widget, which allows panning and scrolling the large image. Please see my edit2 for my new findings about image size.

Comment: Okay, with respect to the different sizes I have no idea why that should be happening.

Comment: I have tried using your math but it seems to be off for some reason. It's not showing at the expected position.

Comment: The math is right so something else might be going on there. Try StackFit.loose on the Stack's fit property let's see if it works.